# Prevent gnome-terminal from changing directory when creating a new tab or window

Tags: command-line, gnome, gnome-terminal

If I have changed directory in gnome-terminal away from `$HOME`, to i.e. `$HOME/foo`, then create a new tab or window, this new tab or window will have `$HOME/foo` as the current working directory instead of `$HOME`. This is new and alien to me and I prefer the old, standard behaviour of all new terminal instances being in `$HOME`.

I would like to acheive this without modifying my user's `.profile` or `.bashrc` (with a `cd` line or whatever). I am running gnome-terminal 3.18.3 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: I was about to post _the_ proper way of doing this (avoid emitting OSC 7 from PROMPT_COMMAND)... but then it occurred to me that Ubuntu has a patch that would stop this from working :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I  get it work by setting a custome command in profile settings, command tab.

From top menu: `Edit` -> `Profile Preference`.

Then `command` tab, check the *Run custom command instead of my shell* and set `/bin/bash` as your custom command.

To run the default shell instead of bash use:

```
/bin/sh -c '`/usr/bin/getent passwd $USER | cut -d: -f7`'
```

instead `/bin/bash` as your custom command.

[image]

---

I'm not sure what is the cause of problem, However I thing each time you create a new tab gnome-terminal forks your current instance, so it's going to inherit your old tab's working directory, but when you set a custom command it's going to create a new instance each time.

Thats only what I think is happening here.

Comment: This works. Although it means gnome-terminal no longer respects the user shell setting from /etc/passwd so it will be confusing if you decide to change shell (to fish, zsh or something) with chsh.

I don't understand why it works though. My shell is already /bin/bash.

Comment: @sapht Updated the answer again, maybe gives you a clue this time ;)

Comment: Clever, but why does it help? There must be some init script that is not being sourced by gnome-terminal when an explicit shell is chosen, right? If the behaviour is hardcoded I'm filing a bug.

Comment: I don't think that it's a bug, I'm not using gnome, however I looked around `gconf-editor` to find anything about `gnome-terminal` but no luck. As I remember my terminals always behaved this way ... so it's nothing new to me; Also I like it this way better.